# How to add time in saved filename?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add the time the document is saved to the filename?

Now it only gets the date, but I would like to add time in this format: 20210111 15:56 Testing.

```vb
comp = Environ("username")
fname = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Testing\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & " Testing " & ".xlsx"
MsgBox "Correct saved" & vbNewLine & "Yes"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Comment: You cant use : because it is one of the characters such as /,\,*,? that cant be used in the file name. Without that you could use `yyyymmdd hhnn` perhaps.

Comment: yyyymmdd-hh.mm works great hehe thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem:

```
comp = Environ("username")
fname = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Testing\" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hh.mm") & " 
Testing " & ".xlsx"
MsgBox "Correct saved" & vbNewLine & "Yes"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```